# Dimension problems in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: dimensions, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm having some dimensions problems but I've checked all the constraints dimensions and there doesn't seem to be an error, if someone could help me I would appreciate it.

```
# Librerias necesarias 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import minimize  

# Constantes de eficiencia de los conversores del EH
# CHP 
n_W = 0.3 # Electricidad 
n_Q = 0.45 # Termal 

# AB 
n_T = 0.8 # Termal 

# CERG 
COP_CERG = 3 

# WARG 
COP_WARG = 0.7  

# Limites superiores 
v_p_CHP = np.array([0,300,450,0]) 
v_p_AB = np.array([0,0,900,0])
v_p_CERG = np.array([0,0,0,400]) 
v_p_WARG = np.array([0,0,0,400]) 

# Limites inferiores 
v_d_CHP = np.array([0,300/2,450/2,0]) 
v_d_AB = np.array([0,0,0,0])
v_d_CERG = np.array([0,0,0,0]) 
v_d_WARG = np.array([0,0,0,0])  

# Precio del gas 
P_g = 0.02 #kW/h 

# Precio electricidad 
P_e = np.array([0,40,20,35,40,60,110,120,115,75,80,120,90,70,60,40])  
# Demanda de electricidad, calefacción y refrigeración 
D_h = np.array([0,200,320,400,580,550,520,500,470,420,320,200])
D_e = np.array([0,150,210,180,175,180,210,160]) 
D_c = np.array([0,0,25,50,75,125,150,125,75,50,25,0])  

# Matrices de espeficicacion por componente 
M = 4 # Numero de vectores de energia (Electricidad,gas,calefaccion y regrigeracion) 
zero_vect_v = np.zeros((1,4)) 
zero_vect_h = np.zeros((4,1))

# H_CHP  
H_CHP = np.array([[0,0,0,0],
                  [n_W,0,0,0],
                  [n_Q,0,0,0], 
                  [0,0,0,0]]) 
# H_AB 
H_AB = np.array([[0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0],
                 [n_T,0,0,0], 
                 [0,0,0,0]]) 
# H_WARG  
H_WARG = np.array([[0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0], 
                   [0,0,COP_WARG,0]])
# H_CERG  
H_CERG = np.array([[0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0],
                   [0,0,0,0], 
                   [0,COP_CERG,0,0]]) 

# Matrices de interconección 
def T_o_AB(X): 
  return np.diag([0,0,X[5],0])  

def T_o_CHP(X): 
  return np.diag([0,X[2],X[3],0]) 

T_o_CERG = np.diag([0,0,0,1]) 
T_o_WARG = np.diag([0,0,0,1]) 

def T_o_EDS(X): 
  return np.diag([0,X[0],0,0]) 

def T_AB_i(X): 
  return np.diag([1-X[1],0,0,0]) 

def T_CHP_i(X): 
  return np.diag([X[1],0,0,0]) 

def T_CERG_CHP(X): 
  return np.diag([0,1-X[2],0,0]) 

def T_CERG_i(X): 
  return np.diag([0,1,1-X[0],0]) 

def T_WARG_AB(X): 
  return np.diag([0,0,1-X[5],0]) 

def T_WARG_CHP(X): 
  return np.diag([0,0,X[4],0])  

T_zero = np.zeros((M,M)) 
I = np.identity(M)

# Costo de la electricidad por horas
# Dominio del tiempo (rangos de tiempo) 
P_tiempo = np.arange(1,25,1) 
# Definicion del vector de demanda eléctrica 
P_e_vect_1 = np.zeros((P_tiempo.shape[0]))
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>=0) & (P_tiempo<=2)] = P_e[1]  
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>2) & (P_tiempo<=6)] = P_e[2] 
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>6) & (P_tiempo<=7)] = P_e[3]
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>7) & (P_tiempo<=8)] = P_e[4] 
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>8) & (P_tiempo<=9)] = P_e[5]
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>9) & (P_tiempo<=10)] = P_e[6]
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>10) & (P_tiempo<=12)] = P_e[7] 
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>12) & (P_tiempo<=13)] = P_e[8]  

P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>13) & (P_tiempo<=15)] = P_e[9]  
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>15) & (P_tiempo<=19)] = P_e[10]  
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>19) & (P_tiempo<=20)] = P_e[11]  
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>20) & (P_tiempo<=21)] = P_e[12]  
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>21) & (P_tiempo<=22)] = P_e[13]  
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>22) & (P_tiempo<=23)] = P_e[14]    
P_e_vect_1[(P_tiempo>23) & (P_tiempo<=24)] = P_e[15]    

P_e_vect_1 = P_e_vect_1/1000

# Demanda 
# Definicion del vector para demanda electricidad
P_e_vect_d_1 = np.zeros((P_tiempo.shape[0]))
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=0) & (P_tiempo<=8)] = D_e[1]  
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>8) & (P_tiempo<=12)] = D_e[2] 
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>12) & (P_tiempo<=15)] = D_e[3]
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>15) & (P_tiempo<=18)] = D_e[4] 
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>18) & (P_tiempo<=19)] = D_e[5]
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>19) & (P_tiempo<=20)] = D_e[6] 
P_e_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>20) & (P_tiempo<=24)] = D_e[7]   

# Definicion del vector para demanda refrigeracion
P_c_vect_d_1 = np.zeros((P_tiempo.shape[0])) 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=0) & (P_tiempo<=9)] = D_c[1] 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=9) & (P_tiempo<=10)] = D_c[2]
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=10) & (P_tiempo<=12)] = D_c[3]
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=12) & (P_tiempo<=13)] = D_c[4]
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=13) & (P_tiempo<=14)] = D_c[5] 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=14) & (P_tiempo<=15)] = D_c[6] 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=15) & (P_tiempo<=16)] = D_c[7] 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=16) & (P_tiempo<=17)] = D_c[8] 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=17) & (P_tiempo<=18)] = D_c[9] 
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=18) & (P_tiempo<=19)] = D_c[10]
P_c_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=19) & (P_tiempo<=24)] = D_c[11] 

# Definicion del vector para demanda calefaccion 
P_h_vect_d_1 = np.zeros((P_tiempo.shape[0])) 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=0) & (P_tiempo<=6)] = D_h[1]   
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=6) & (P_tiempo<=7)] = D_h[2] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=7) & (P_tiempo<=8)] = D_h[3] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=8) & (P_tiempo<=12)] = D_h[4] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=12) & (P_tiempo<=13)] = D_h[5] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=13) & (P_tiempo<=14)] = D_h[6]  
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=14) & (P_tiempo<=16)] = D_h[7] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=16) & (P_tiempo<=17)] = D_h[8] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=17) & (P_tiempo<=21)] = D_h[9]  
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=21) & (P_tiempo<=23)] = D_h[10] 
P_h_vect_d_1[(P_tiempo>=23) & (P_tiempo<=24)] = D_h[11] 

# Arreglo de dimensiones 
P_e_vect_d_1 = np.array([P_e_vect_d_1]) 
P_c_vect_d_1 = np.array([P_c_vect_d_1]) 
P_h_vect_d_1 = np.array([P_h_vect_d_1])

# Concatenar los vectores de demanda 
Vout = np.concatenate((np.zeros((1,24)),P_e_vect_d_1,P_h_vect_d_1,P_c_vect_d_1),axis=0)   
Vout = Vout.T 

# Construccion de matriz H 
def H_matrix(X): 
  return T_o_EDS(X)*I + T_o_AB(X)*H_AB*T_AB_i(X)*I + T_o_CHP(X)*H_CHP*T_CHP_i(X)*I + T_o_CERG@H_CERG*(T_CERG_i(X)*I + T_CERG_CHP(X)*H_CHP*T_CHP_i(X)*I) + T_o_WARG@H_WARG*(T_WARG_AB(X)*H_AB*T_AB_i(X)*I + T_WARG_CHP(X)*H_CHP*T_CHP_i(X)*I) 

save_results = [] # Lista para guardar los resultados  

# Problema de optimizacion 
for t in P_tiempo: 
  # Definicion de la funcion de costo 
  def objective_function(X): 
    return P_e_vect_1[t-1]*X[7] + P_g*X[6]  

  # Restricciones  
  cons = ({'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda X: H_matrix(X)@np.array([[X[6]],[X[7]],[0],[0]]) - Vout[t-1,:].T }, 
        {'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda X: H_CHP@np.array([[X[1]*X[6]],[0],[0],[0]]) - np.array([[0],[X[8]],[X[9]],[0]])}, 
        {'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda X: H_AB@np.array([[(1-X[1])*X[6]],[0],[0],[0]]) - np.array([[0],[0],[X[10]],[0]])},  
        {'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda X: H_WARG@np.array([[0],[0],[X[4]*X[9]+(1-X[5])*X[10]],[0]]) - np.array([[0],[0],[0],[X[12]]])},
        {'type': 'eq',
        'fun': lambda X: H_CERG@np.array([[0],[(1-X[0])*X[7]+(1-X[2])*X[8]],[0],[0]]) - np.array([[0],[0],[0],[X[11]]])},
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: -(X[0]-1)*X[7]},
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: -(H_CHP@np.array([[X[1]*X[6]],[0],[0],[0]]) - v_p_CHP.T)}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: -(H_AB@np.array([[(1-X[1])*X[6]],[0],[0],[0]]) - v_p_AB.T)}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: -(H_WARG@np.array([[0],[0],[X[4]*X[9]+(1-X[5])*X[10]],[0]]) - v_p_WARG.T)}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: -(H_CERG@np.array([[0],[(1-X[0])*X[7]+(1-X[2])*X[8]],[0],[0]]) - v_p_CERG.T)}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: -(v_d_CHP.T - H_CHP@np.array([[X[1]*X[6]],[0],[0],[0]]))}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: (H_AB@np.array([[(1-X[1])*X[6]],[0],[0],[0]]))}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: (H_WARG@np.array([[0],[0],[X[4]*X[9]+(1-X[5])*X[10]],[0]]))}, 
        {'type': 'ineq',
        'fun': lambda X: (H_CERG@np.array([[0],[(1-X[0])*X[7]+(1-X[2])*X[8]],[0],[0]]))})  
  
# Condicion inicial  
  if t == 1:
    x0 = np.zeros((13,1))
  else: 
    x0 = save_results[t-2]

  # Bounds 
  bnds = ((0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1),(0, 1),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None),(0, None)) 
  # Problema de optimizacion
  sol = minimize(objective_function,x0,constraints=cons,bounds=bnds)  
  solution = sol.x
  save_results.append(solution)
```

It shows this error: ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 4 and the array at index 1 has size 1.

I look at the eq constraints because apparently the error's there but all the dimensions of the matrices and vector match.